# MySQL JOIN and SUM performance issue

Tags: mysql, join

I'm having an issue with MySQL JOIN and SUM. Because my JOIN has multiple matches I will do a SELECT in the JOIN so it won't sum to much.

**The problem:**
My query is terribly slow. In the test setup below it runs in just 1ms without any indexes. But on my production database this query takes ~4 seconds when selecting just one single record (`WHERE id = X`).

Table a has ~700.000 records
Table b has ~800.000 records
Table c has ~45.000 records

Table a has index on `id`
Table b has index on `id`, `a_id`
Table c has index on `id`, `a_id`

Below the simplified tables and used Query.

Table `a`

```
id
---
1
```

Table `b`

```
id | a_id | amount | price
--------------------------
 1 |    1 |      1 |    25
 2 |    1 |      1 |    20
```

Table `c`

```
id | a_id | amount | price
--------------------------
 1 |    1 |      1 |    23
 2 |    1 |      1 |    20
```

**The Query:**
Now when I run this query to get the sum of `b` and `c` that have a reference in table `a`.

```
SELECT id, bPrice, cPrice
FROM a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT a_id, SUM(amount * price) AS bPrice FROM b GROUP BY a_id) bb ON a.id = bb.a_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT a_id, SUM(amount * price) AS cPrice FROM c GROUP BY a_id) cc ON a.id = cc.a_id
```

Wrong result but fast

```
SELECT 
    a.id,
    SUM(b.amount * b.price) AS bPrice,
    SUM(c.amount * c.price) AS cPrice
FROM a
JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id
JOIN c ON a.id = c.a_id;
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e13691/4)

Comment: No indexes on `a_id` in either `b` or `c`?

Answer (score 2):

MySQL will struggle to pull the index through from the sub queries to join against, and suspect you are joining a LOT of rows from the sub queries.

As an initial step, you could try removing one of the sub queries to just change it to a join against the main table.

```
SELECT id, 
        SUM(b.amount * b.price) AS bPrice, 
        cPrice
FROM a
LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT a_id, 
            SUM(amount * price) AS cPrice 
    FROM c 
    GROUP BY a_id
) cc ON a.id = cc.a_id
GROUP BY a.id,
        cc.cPrice
```

Comment: This query is failing, see last line `cc.cPrice`

Comment: Missed a comma. Fixed it now

Comment: OK, this runs in ~ 80ms when I also add a `WHERE a.id = ''`. When I run it al the whole database, 800k records, it runs in ~ 9 seconds. For all 800k records, this is acceptable, and for a single record 80ms is also acceptable, coming from 4000ms! Tnx!

Comment: @Timo002 - Can you confirm your indexes please? You question says _Table b has index on id, a_id_ but that does not match SQL Fiddle. If it is a single index covering both columns then it won't help much with the sub query, but if it is 2 separate indexes it might help.

Comment: Indexes in the SQL Fiddle are missing. In the production database I have indexes on the table as mentioned in the start question. Separate indexes on both columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
select set1.id,set1.bPrice,set2.cPrice from (SELECT a.id,SUM(b.amount * b.price) AS bPrice FROM a JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id) as set1
JOIN
(SELECT a.id,SUM(c.amount * c.price) AS cPrice FROM a JOIN c ON a.id = c.a_id) as set2 ON set1.id = set2.id
```

Comment: This query also runs in ~4 seconds, so not faster. Also I added `GROUP BY a.id` to the JOIN queries

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth a try to subquery - sometimes they can be quicker:

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    (SELECT SUM(amount * price) AS bPrice FROM b where b.a_id = a.id) AS bPrice, 
    (SELECT SUM(amount * price) AS cPrice FROM c where c.a_id = a.id) AS cPrice
FROM a
```